# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showMessageBox' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

If I try to open a `dialog.showMessageBox` in Electron it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showMessageBox' of undefined`

Here the full Code:

```
      if (name == '') {
        const { dialog } = require('electron')
        dialog.showMessageBox(null);

      }
```

I tried the `require('electron').remote` module but that didn't produce an output that was near ok and I also tried reinstalling electron which didn't work, so I'm left with just the error.

Comment: Well I'll state the obvious that the `dialog` in your case is `undefined` and it is hard to tell you why it is based on this small code snipped that you showed.

Comment: "I tried the require('electron').remote module but that didn't produce an output that was near ok". Using remote is the way to go! What is "not near ok"?

Comment: @pergy it looked weird and a little bit out of place but it will be ok for my purpose but it would be nicer to handle it without the .remote module :)